# Creating an HTTPS connection in Akka Http

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream, akka-http

In the documentation "http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.11/scala/http/client-side/client-https-support.html#hostname-verification" it says that outgoingConnectionTls is used, but that method name seems to have changed to outgoingConnectionHttps.

I have code working (gave back json response as string) using akka-http-core 1.0 that works, but updating to the most recent version (2.4.xx) seems to break it, even though it looks like the newer named outgoingConnectionHttps is all that changed. Now my result is simply "List()" When I try to Unmarshal the response entity.

Can anyone help with this? The code that was working is shown below

```
package com.packt.akka

import akka.actor.ActorSystem
import akka.http.scaladsl.Http
import akka.http.scaladsl.model._
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.headers.BasicHttpCredentials
import akka.http.scaladsl.model.StatusCodes._
import akka.http.scaladsl.unmarshalling.Unmarshal
import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
import akka.stream.scaladsl._
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory

import scala.concurrent.Future

object JiraConnectionLevel extends App {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem()
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  implicit val ec = system.dispatcher

  val config = ConfigFactory.load()


  val name = config.getString("auth.jira.user")
  val password = config.getString("auth.jira.password")
  val host = config.getString("services.jira.host")
  val jiraUri = config.getString("services.jira.uri")

  val authorization = headers.Authorization(BasicHttpCredentials(name, password))

  val connectionFlow: Flow[HttpRequest, HttpResponse, Future[Http.OutgoingConnection]]=
    //This is where the method name changed it was Http().outgoingConnectionTls(host) which worked
    Http().outgoingConnectionHttps(host)



  val responseFuture =
    Source.single(HttpRequest(headers = List(authorization),uri = jiraUri))
    .via(connectionFlow)
    .runWith(Sink.head)

  responseFuture map { res =>
    res.status match {
      case OK =>
        println(s"Response is:"+ Unmarshal(res.entity).to[String])
          }
      case _ =>
        Unmarshal(res.entity).to[String].map { body =>
          println(s"The response status is ${res.status} and response body is ${body}")
          shutdown()
        }
    }
  }

  def shutdown() = {
    Http().shutdownAllConnectionPools().onComplete{ _ =>
      system.shutdown()
      system.awaitTermination()
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: I'm on akka 2.4.11 and your code works for me. I'd test it from another client such as Chome Postman extension. Maybe there is problem with authentication or maybe server has bad selfsigned SSL certificate. Could be anything.